# (Primefaces 6.0) p:media doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: html, primefaces

i'm trying to load mp3,mp4 (via p:media) from database.
For some reason it's working only on Firefox, but on Chrome it won't load..

xhtml code

```
<p:media value="#{javaBean.streamAudio}" cache="false" width="100%" player="flash"/>
```

with

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "javaBean")
public class Blahblah {
  public StreamedContent getStreamAudio() throws IOException {

         FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

         if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();
         } else {;
             return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), "audio/mp3");
         }

      }

}
```

Comment: That sounds like a difference how these browsers handle the content. I suspect that especially the ``player="flash"`` might make a difference here. Anyways, that question is really hard to answer as it is.

Comment: That was an example for mp3...                                                                  
mp4 is same, but with "video/mp4"

Comment: @f1sh Maybe, but flash is only player supported for mp3.. Maybe there is a way with audio tag ?